# Trabalhando com Data no ngInit

Tags: angularjs, django, data

Tenho um input em meu formulário de data. Sempre que o usuário modificar a data, será atualizado no Django e retornará outra data.

Quando o usuário entra na tela, eu já trago a data da seguinte forma: `1996-10-01`

**Input**

```
<input type="date" ng-model="myobject.date" ng-change="updateField()" ng-init="myobject.date = '{{djangoobj.date}}'">
```

Quando eu tento apenas colocar o valor do django no input, parece que o `ng-model` sobrescreve e fica tudo em branco o campo. Então eu sempre uso o NG-INIT para inicializar o `ng-model` com o valor do Django. Porém, quando eu tento fazer isso com um campo de data, recebo a seguinte mensagem de erro:

```
Expected `1996-10-01` to be a date
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Expected `1996-10-01` to be a date
```

Conforme o erro, você está inserindo uma `String`, mas é esperado um objeto do tipo `Date`. Basta via javascript converter, exemplo: `new Date('1996-10-01')`.

O ideal é fazer tudo isso via Ajax, receber os dados e alimentar o `$scope`. Na forma que você está fazendo, poderia colocar no `ng-init` uma função para converter a `String` para `Date` e atualizar o `ng-model`.

```
<input type="date" ng-model="myobject.date" ng-change="updateField()" ng-init="converter('{{djangoobj.date}}')"
```

e no controller:

```
$scope.converter = function(s){
    $scope.myobject.date = new Date(s);
}
```